# remove duplicates from List?

Tags: android, laravel, api, android-studio

I am getting duplicate items from an API in my adapter but I want to remove those duplicates from my side means from my adapter and print it once any idea how? Thanks in advance.
got: duplicate rows in my cardview but through an API.
want: just want to print it once and remove those duplicates.

MyAdapter:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull catView holder, int position) {

        holder.id.setText(oilResponses.get(position).getId());

       }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (oilResponses.size() != 0) {
            return oilResponses.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
    private void oilList() {
        Api.getClient().do_oil(CAR_ID)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<List<OilResponse>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NotNull List<OilResponse> responses) {
                        oilAdapter = new OilAdapter(responses);
                        oilRecycler.setAdapter(oilAdapter);
                        

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NotNull Throwable e) {
                    
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Hey Zaidi, welcome to stackoverflow. I'm afraid your question has a bit quite a lot of code, please try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @itaishz thanks for your response I have updated my question.

Comment: Why not filter it by id?

Comment: Hi there, actually there is no filtration I have items in my cardview which just shows ids but I am getting duplicate items from an API so I wanna avoid those duplicates from my side.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to save them in a `Set` instead of a `List`, it is basically the same thing but in a set each object can be saved one time, so you can't have duplicates even if you'd like to.

Comment: Hi there, I tried it converting List to Set but as we all know that in adapter on BindViewHolder we use list.get(position).getId(); but with Set I cannot get it.